# Create an floating action button using Bootstrap and Angular 5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, angular5

I'm trying to create a floating action button, that once clicked expands two more floating action buttons.

*Example:*

[image: floating action button]

Comment: Provide some code. Where does the error occur? A little more information is necessary to be able to help...

Comment: You may want to use a [dropup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation), that you can customize a bit.

Comment: https://propeller.in/components/floating-button.php check this out.